# Number of anagrams in an array of words (Codewars)

Tags: python, performance, beginner, algorithm

[Codewars Kata in Question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/number-of-anagrams-in-an-array-of-words/train/python).

> An anagram is a word, a phrase, or a sentence formed from another by
>   rearranging its letters. An example of this is "angel", which is an
>   anagram of "glean".
>
> Write a function that receives an array of words, and returns the
>   total number of distinct pairs of anagramic words inside it.
>
> Some examples:
>
> There are 2 anagrams in the array `["dell", "ledl", "abc", "cba"]`
>
> There are 7 anagrams in the array `["dell", "ledl", "abc", "cba", "bca", "bac"]`

My code is usually not optimal, and I would like to improve my coding practices, and coding sense which is why I try to put up for review all nontrivial code I write.

#### My Code

```
from collections import Counter
import math

def choose(n, k):   #Each distinct anagram pair is a selection from the set of all words that have the same count.
    f = math.factorial
    return (f(n)//(f(n-k)*f(k)))

def anagram_counter(words):
    words = list(set(words))    #Suppress duplicates.
    unique = set()  #Set of unique words.
    count = {}  #Dictionary that stores the count for each word.
    unique = set()
    for word in words:
        #The current word is not an anagram of any word already in the set.
        wordID = Counter(word)      
        if not unique or all((wordID != count[distinct][1] for distinct in unique)):
            unique.add(word)
            count[word] = [1,wordID]    #A tuple containing number of anagrams of a word and its `wordID`.
        else:   #If the current word is an anagram of a word already in the set.
            for distinct in list(unique):
                if count[distinct][1] == wordID:    #If the word is an anagram of a preexisting word.
                    count[distinct][0] += 1     #Increment the counter.
                    break
    return 0 if count == {} else sum((choose(itm[0], 2) for itm in count.values() if itm[0] > 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your life too difficult, IMO. Whenever you iterate over all members of a `set` to see if some element is in it or write `list(unique)`, you are probably doing something wrong.

I would just transform each word into a canonical form (you could choose a `frozenset` of the `Counter` items or just a sorted string). Then just count how often each appears:

```
def anagram_counter(words):
    count = Counter(frozenset(Counter(word).items()) for word in words)
    return sum(choose(x, 2) for x in count.values() if x > 1)

def anagram_counter2(words):
    count = Counter("".join(sorted(word)) for word in words)
    return sum(choose(x, 2) for x in count.values() if x > 1)
```

You could optimize the last line by using `Counter.most_common` and stopping as soon as you get to the elements that appeared only once:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def anagram_counter3(words):
    count = Counter("".join(sorted(word)) for word in words)
    return sum(choose(x[1], 2)
               for x in takewhile(lambda t: t[1] > 1, count.most_common()))
```

Comparing the timings for some small input:

```
x = ["foo", "bar", "oof", "rab", "foobar"]
%timeit anagram_counter(x)
# 27.2 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit anagram_counter2(x)
# 9.71 µs ± 656 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit anagram_counter3(x)
# 11.9 µs ± 492 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit anagram_counter_op(x)
# 25.6 µs ± 472 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

And for some larger inputs:

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np

# increasing number of words, always 5 letters
x1 = [["".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5)) for _ in range(n)]
     for n in np.logspace(1, 4, num=10, dtype=int)]
# increasing length of words, always 500 words
x2 = [["".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=n)) for _ in range(500)]
     for n in np.logspace(1, 4, num=10, dtype=int)]
```

[image]

[image]

(Note that both axis are logarithmic on both plots.)

Answer (score 2):

Graipher answer is nice, but there is one possible inefficiency not taken into account: choice.

If you have a lot of anagrams, it's better to replace the generic version with the explicit formula for pair:

```
def count_pairs(n):
    return  (n * (n-1)) // 2
```

here some timings, with a big list with only a few different canonical anagrams:

```
def random_anagram(w):
    l = w[:]
    random.shuffle(l)
    return "".join(l)

base_anagrams = [random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=30) for i in range(4)]

x4 = [random_anagram(random.choice(base_anagrams)) for _ in range(100000)]

def anagram_counter5(words):                                            
    count = Counter("".join(sorted(word)) for word in words)
    return sum(count_pairs(x) for x in count.values() if x > 1)
```

gives on my machine

```
%timeit anagram_counter2(x)
353 ms ± 2.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit anagram_counter5(x)
253 ms ± 4.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```